# Scrapy Google Search

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to **scrape** google search and people also search links.

Example when you go on google and you search for "Christopher Nolan". Google also produces a "people also search for"  which includes images of people related to the our search. In this case our People also search produces (Christian bale, Emma Thomas, Zack Synder etc). I am interested in scraping this data.

I am using `scrapy` framework and wrote a simple **scraper** but it returns an empty CSV data file. Below is code I have so far your help is appreciated. Hope everything is clear in what i want to achieve. I used Xpath helper (google app) to help find the Xpath.

My code:

```
# PyGSSpider(spidder folder)
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from PyGoogleSearch.items import PyGSItem
import sys

class PyGSSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "google"
    allowed_domains = ["www.google.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com/#q=christopher+nolan"]

    #Extracts Christopher Nolan link     
    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("https://www.google.com/search?q=christpher+noaln&oq=christpher+noaln&aqs")), follow=True),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item')
    ]
   
    #Parse function for extracting the people also search link.
    def parse_item(self,response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
        sel=Selector(response)
        item=PyGSItem()
        item['peoplealsosearchfor'] = sel.xpath('//div[@id="cnt"]/@href').extract()
       
        return item
```

items.py:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class PyGSItem(Item):
    peoplealsosearchfor = Field()
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for help with?

Comment: Am how i can scrap the people also search for links

Answer (score 0):

The reason this won't work is because Google enforcer an algorithm which prevents bots from using their search.

However using Selenium might do the trick.