# Scrapy cnn.com search

Tags: python, search, scrapy

I've got a problem with using Scrapy for getting data from cnn.com search results. For example, we have a link https://edition.cnn.com/search/?q=war
In a browser it looks fine. Scrapy shell returns something unsatisfying when I type "view(response)": "Your search did not match any documents. Try using less limited search criteria and maybe we can find something."
I was going to get all the links from each search result page and parse every article that suits a given query ("war" in this example).

Screenshots:

[The page in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4kr7.jpg)

[The same with opened dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2vnN.jpg)

[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Mp5R.jpg)

[View response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idfe9.jpg)

I've found one somewhat related case: [Scrapy Google Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840059/scrapy-google-search)
Does my question have the same roots and cnn.com is blocking bots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page does not load data, because this page use javascript, you can use

[Toggle JavaScript](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggle-javascript/cidlcjdalomndpeagkjpnefhljffbnlo) extention to load the page without javascript.

You need to find the javascript file that load the items in the page.

Comment: Thank you. You're really right. I disabled JavaScript with your browser extension, and the page turned out exactly as Scrapy sees it. Do you recommend using Splash as in this article - https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash ? Or what did you mean writing "You need to find the .js that load the items in the page"?

Comment: I don't recommend to use Splash because es heavy but when the page es so hard to crawling, It's the best option.
When you crawling a page some time the page use a javascript file to load the data, only you need to find the javascript file that load the items in the page, some times is a extra request. You need to inspect every file that loads the page to know how this information is loading

Comment: Ok, @Justo , I'll figure out how to use dev tools and find required js file. I need some time to do it. Thank you again

Comment: I solved the problem with your advice and after reading an appropriate article in Scrapy docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html  It turned out that search results can be found in queries https://search.api.cnn.io/content?q=war&size=10 , https://search.api.cnn.io/content?q=war&size=10&from=10&page=2, etc

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a search on this website from a browser, a cookie is POST-ed to the backend with data about your computer (geolocalization, language and much more)
My guess is that the backend only performs the query if the cookie is present.

You can pass the cookie in your scrapy Request with **cookie=** build parameter.

If this fail (like, if the cookie contains a token that changes everytime) you can also try to scrape the website using Selenium.

Comment: Thank you @matthieu.cham . I've found in docs some information about it: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=request#request-objects What to write as a "cookies" parameters in Request? You said: "build parameter". As I got from docs, there should be some dict with something specific for the website cookies... Could you please clarify this point? I didn't manage cookies and a website backend before

Comment: It's hard to be specific because you have not posted your code. cookies= is an arg of Request, i.e. if your Spider does yield Request(url) somewhere, you can try to yield Request(url, cookies=*same cookie values as in browser*) instead

Comment: My code is just a Scrapy shell few commands so far. I tried to reach some search results and stumbled upon an empty page.  It turned out that search results can be found in queries https://search.api.cnn.io/content?q=war&size=10 , https://search.api.cnn.io/content?q=war&size=10&from=10&page=2, etc I think it's enough for me, I can parse json files